# Conditional operator used in cout statement

Tags: c++, conditional-operator

By trying, I came to know that it is necessary to put parentheses around a conditional operator in a cout statement. Here a small example:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  int a = 5;
  float b = (a!=0) ? 42.0f : -42.0f;
  // works fine
  std::cout << b << std::endl;
  // works also fine
  std::cout << ( (a != 0) ? 42.0f : -42.0f ) << std::endl;
  // does not work fine
  std::cout << (a != 0) ? 42.0f : -42.0f;

  return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
42
42
1
```

Why are these parentheses necessary? The resulting type of the conditional operator is known in both cases, isn't it?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The `?:` operator has lower precedence than the `<<` operator i.e., the compiler interprets your last statement as:

```
(std::cout << (a != 0)) ? 42.0f : -42.0f;
```

Which will first stream the boolean value of `(a!=0)` to cout.  Then the result of that expression (i.e., a reference to cout) will be cast to an appropriate type for use in the ?: operator (namely `void*`: see [cplusplus.com](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ios/operator_voidpt/)), and depending on whether that value is true (i.e., whether cout has no error flags set), it will grab either the value 42 or the value -42.  Finally, it will throw that value away (since nothing uses it).

Comment: Just a note, `cout<<` returns `cout`, not anything about valid state. failbit/badbit will be set, but `(std::cout << (a != 0)) ` always returns a reference to `std::cout`. `-42.0f` should never be returned, as that reference should always boolean evaluate to true.

Comment: @SamDeHaan: yes.  Sorry, I was perhaps being a little sloppy in my explanation.  The expression "cout<<x" returns cout.  But in order for the expression "cout?a:b" to be evaluated, cout must first be cast to some value that's a valid operand to the ?: operator.  In this case, it is (operator void*) that does the work.  That operator returns NULL iff an error flag is set.  See: <http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ios/operator_voidpt/>

Comment: And there I go trying to sound smart again. Thanks for the correction to my correction. :)

Comment: Since C++11, it's not `operator void*`, but `explicit operator bool` http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool

Answer (score 7):

Because `<<` has higher precedence than `?`.

Fun exercise:

```
float ftest = std::cout << (a != 0) ? 42.0f : -42.0f;
```

Take that, Coding Horror!!!

Your code is equivalent to:

```
if ( std::cout << (a != 0) )
     42.0f;
else
    -42.0f;
```

It outputs `1` because, well, `(a != 0) == true`;

Answer (score 1):

By the way, this can also work:

```
a != 0 ? std::cout << 42.0f : std::cout << -42.0f;
```

In my opinion it is better to use this way because:

1. It also works in the case, where we want to output different data types (telling from my experience)
   For example, if had to do something like this:

   ```
    std::cout << (a != 0 ? 42.0f : "Not zero!");
   ```

   Will generate an error because one expression is of `float` type and the other is of `char*` type, but you can write it like this :

   ```
    a != 0 ? std::cout << 42.0f : cout << "Not zero!";
   ```

   This works because expressions in the conditional statement must have same data type value, and `std::cout` returns the same data type no matter what it is being output through it.
2. (Minor reason) No parenthesis - You don't have to deal with parenthesis as `<<` have higher precedence over `?:` as stated in the above answers as well. This can save us the hassle of matching closing brackets thereby reducing probability of error.