# gcc inconsistent about string type

Tags: c++, gcc, ternary-operator, stdstring, operator-precedence

I have the following test program:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string s;
    std::string a = "sd";

    std::cout << a==s ? "y" : "n";

    return 0;
}
```

Trying to compile this with `g++ test.cpp` gives the following cryptic error:

```
error: no match for 'operator==' (operand types are 'std::basic_ostream<char>' and 'std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}')
  std::cout << a==s ? "y" : "n";
                ^
```

It seems that `s` is being correctly compiled as type `std::string`, while `a` is being compiled as `std::basic_ostream<char>`!? HELP!!

Comment: Put parentheses (i.e., `std::cout << (a==s ? "y" : "n");`).

Comment: Due to operator precedence you should wrap your expression in parentheses, i.e. `std::cout << (a==s ? "y" : "n");`.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

Comment: Any downvoters care to explain?

Comment: It's parsed as `((std::cout << a) == s) ? "y" : "n";`, because `<<` binds more tightly than `==`. You'll get a similar error with `std::cout << 1 == 2;`

Comment: @baruch **-1** because this is your 241st question on the Stack and it's not even an [original one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9619424/conditional-operator-used-in-cout-statement)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The compiler parsed your statement as `((std::cout << a) == s) ? "y" : "n";`  because of [operators precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) : You need parentheses.

```
std::cout << (a==s ? "y" : "n");
```

Answer (score 5):

The error message from the compiler is very helpful here. It's saying the LHS of the operator is of type `std::basic_ostream<char>` while the RHS of the operator is of type `std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}`.

i.e. the line

```
std::cout << a==s ? "y" : "n";
```

is being interpreted as

```
(std::cout << a) == s ? "y" : "n";
```

To change the compiler to take the right objects for the == operator, you'll have to use parantheses to override that behavior.

```
std::cout << (a==s ? "y" : "n");
```