# Difference between adding/not adding parenthesis when ternary operator is used as argument to cout

Tags: c++

This question is clearly not a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9619424/conditional-operator-used-in-cout-statement). Here in the original [page](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/cc-ternary-operator-some-interesting-observations/) where I found the two code snippets seems to be giving contradictory reasons and my aim is to get a clarity on that and not just learn about what is given in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9619424/conditional-operator-used-in-cout-statement).

How many times do I have to edit this question to convince everyone that this question is not a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9619424/conditional-operator-used-in-cout-statement). Please read my question in full and also the reference page I gave. They explained it wrong there and I need a clarity on that one. Not jut learn about cout in general.

I came across the following two code snippets in [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/cc-ternary-operator-some-interesting-observations/) page.

First snippet:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int test = 0;
  cout << test ? "A String" : 0 << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Second snippet:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int test = 0;
  cout << (test ? "A String" : 0) << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

It says there that the first code snippet will throw a compile error for sure but the second one may or may not compile.

I do not see any difference between the two. Please explain the difference if at all there is any. In the explanation in [page](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/cc-ternary-operator-some-interesting-observations/) they seem to be giving contradictory reason. I need a clarity on that one.

I do not understand why this question keeps getting negative votes while no one yet marked it as duplicate nor has anyone answered it correctly.

Comment: Please only tag [tag:c] when your question is about the C programming language. This is not.

Comment: [Operator Precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence). And I can't get why it says the 2nd one may not compile.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: I tagged C since the ternary operator is also used in C. This increases my chances of getting the right answer.

Comment: @TARS no it doesn't. Otherwise while at it, you could have added Java for even more confusion.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: Unlike C++ and Java or Python for that matter, C and C++ are closely related languages.

Comment: @songyuanyao: Do you mean to say the first one will compile for sure ?

Comment: @TARS No, I meant the 2nd one should compile. The 1st one shouldn't, of course.

Comment: @TARS They are closely related *but not the same* such that asking about both languages at the same time provokes confusions.

Comment: Why would the second one compile? The first one does not compile since the types of the two expressions are different. In the second one also the types are different. So why would it compile?

Comment: @TARS `"A String"` could decay to pointer, i.e. `const char*`, and `0` is null pointer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Conditional operator used in cout statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9619424/conditional-operator-used-in-cout-statement)

Answer (score 6):

With operator precedence,

```
cout << test ? "A String" : 0 << endl;
```

is

```
(cout << test) ? "A String" : (0 << endl);
```

With invalid `0 << endl` (and not expected condition for ternary).

Whereas

```
cout << (test ? "A String" : 0) << endl;
```

is what you expect.

Type of ternary operator would be `const char*` which is the common type of:

- `"A String"` (`const char[9]`).
- **literal** `0` (which would be `static_cast<const char*>(nullptr)` in that case and not an `int`).

Comment: So the first one does not compile according to the operator precedence rule while second one won't compile since the return types for the third expression in the ternary is not convertible to the return type of second operator right ?

Comment: @TARS No, the second snippet compiles, because `0` is convertible to `const char *`, so it is valid code.

Comment: The reason they gave for the first code snippet not to compile in the page is as follows:

"The following program will not compile, because the compiler is unable to find return type of ternary expression or implicit conversion is unavailable between exp2 (char array) and exp3 (int)."
This is not the real reason right according to your answer?

Comment: @TARS: [Demo](https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/XNY0jNxyJq) using there site gives error I state. As `0 << endl` is invalid, to continue parsing and provide other error, compiler might use default type (as `int`), and then ternary operator also gives an error.